# Redirect to PayPal breaks sessions

Tags: php, session, lamp

I am running into an issue with a redirect and sessions.

The flow of the applications is this:

Customer goes to site
Adds product to cart
Selects to checkout with PayPal
Is redirected to PayPal
Logs in to PayPal
Redirected back to site
Continues through billing/shipping pages
Confirms the order and submits

This is working in development without an issue.

When I go to the live server, the session keeps getting lost after the redirect to PayPal.

Any idea what it could be?

Extra Info:

I found that when I first go to the website, I have a session ID.

When I go through the checkout process and I am redirect to PayPal, then directed back to the return URL (back to the merchant website), the same session ID is in the cookie. So it looks like the session is not being restarted, but rather that the session data is just empty.

Comment: are you calling  `session_regenerate_id` after you start your sessions?

Comment: Is the live server just one machine? Does the session cookie get set using the same hostname as PayPal redirects back to?

Comment: Make sure if you start the session on `http://www.example.com` that Paypal doesn't redirect you back to `http://example.com` or vice versa.

Comment: Orangepill - I am not.

Comment: Jon - The live server is just one machine, not a load balance or anything like that. original hostname that generates the session is the same hostname as the customer is returned to after PayPal.

Comment: budwiser - Yes I've verified it does not go http to https (its always https) or www to no www.

Comment: budwiser - wait a sec, no. the return comes in as http instead of https. I am going to fix that and see if it works.

Comment: budwiser - nope that didnt fix it. Session still doesnt work properly.

Comment: Can you look the cookies sent to the server when your browser requests the pre-PayPal page, and compare them to what's sent when you get to the post-PayPal page?

Comment: Jamie Niemasik - Yes I can. What am I looking for exactly? The session ID?

Comment: Jamie Niemasik - Looking at the session id from when I first hit the site and when I return from PayPal, the session ID is the same.

Comment: Sessions does not allow cross domain if they are not configured correctly because of suhosin patch. Maybe you should disable suhosin in your production server. Look at phpinfo()

Comment: @DavidLevel What do you mean? If PayPal points back to the site of the original request, nothing is cross domain.

Comment: You can send info to PayPal when the user goes there.  PayPal then sends this info back when it redirects back to your site.  Why not store the ID in this information so that it doesn't get lost?

Comment: is the session timing out? Is your redirect script writing blank data to teh session? Are you resetting the basket before sending to Paypal for instance?

Comment: Needs a lot more info, otherwise we're quessing. Are you using your own sessions, or PHP sessions? If your own, check your paths: are you creating the cookie at a "/subdirectory" and then coming back to a different subdirectory? Or have you got two cookies on live server, with different settings (directory/host). How do you know sessionID is the same - from reading the cookie, or by outputting session_id(), or something else? Use code to check the sessionID, not the cookie. Do you have a start session/end session handler? What's the output from session_get_cookie_params()?

Comment: @Sugitime we need more information: is it framework or own code, cause some frameworks with some settings  reset session if user go out from site. also, Paypal IPN should not rely on session, cause there no garanties of immediate answer from Paypal.

Comment: Hello there, I am running into the same problem. So, did you find the solution yet? Please let me know.

Comment: @UjjwalPrajapati sorry I did not find a solution. I ended up saving the data into my internal session db and using the EC token as an ID to correlate the data.

Comment: ok. one more question to @budwiser what if it is the issue of http://example.com and http://www.example.com. How to solve this issue? We are not sure of how the user enter the user as both are valid but the return url should be fixed, isn't it?

Comment: @UjjwalPrajapati Add a rewrite rule that makes the web server to force the user always to the www.-address.

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue, and I found that it's mistake in domain name, as before redirecting to paypal url is

```
'http://www.example.com/paypal-redirect.php'
```

while at the time of return from paypal url is

```
'http://example.com/paypal-return.php'
```

so here I missed **www**, so it might be that, or **http/https** just do check that thing, hope that will help to resolve this issue

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks for this, had me scratching my head for days!

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling session_start() on the page that returns from Paypal?

That is usually the common mistake.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini,
set session.cookie_domain= '.yourdomain.com';
or if you don't have access to it change domain parameter

```
session_set_cookie_params ( lifetime,'/','.yourdomain.com',false);
```

note that you have to call it before session_start();

this would share the session over all subdomains including www.domain.com, this solved my problem. this has the advantage that we need not worry  whether user typed www.domain.com or simply domain.com to access the page.Hope this helps